# Application Loader Help?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am trying to submit my app to application loader but when i press the next button there is no response, no error, nothing. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the stand-alone Application Loader? Use the Organizer in XCode instead. It's better integrated and you might have more luck.